# Visual Studio 2012 fullscreen mode with all opened toolbars from non-fullscreen mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I press Shift+Alt+Enter to enter to fullscreen mode, all toolbars like "Solution Explorer" or "Properties" are automatically hidden (there is only toolbar on the top and code editor). It's a bit annoying. I want everything the same as it was before entering to fullscreen. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

At first time not but..

Visual Studio has a couple of running modes, and each of these modes has it’s own memory. So when you’re in Full Screen, Debug, or Normal mode, Visual Studio will remember your window/panel/toolbar locations for that specific session.

[try this](http://scottcate.com/vstricks/011-visual-studio-full-screen-options/)